# Best approach for adding animation to large text blocks in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to determine the most Vue-centric way of achieving animation of a set of paragraphs, in the form of a progressive reveal UI. I come from a traditional MVC / separation of concerns background and so relatively new to Vue. It is not clear what the purest and most sensible Vue way to achieve this is.

**UI intention**

I have a large block of text which forms a set of documentation. The UI concept being aimed for is that the paragraphs appear progressively. I.e. A is present, then when the button underneath is clicked then A,B are shown, then A,B,C.

```
Long paragraph A
[Read more]

Long paragraph A
Long paragraph B
[Read more]

Long paragraph A
Long paragraph B
Long paragraph C
```

**Traditional progressive-enhancement HTML/JS implementation**

In traditional separation-of-concerns HTML/JS the obviously correct approach is that the content is defined as pure semantic HTML, with a surrounding div, and a JS function is targeted at that div, i.e.

```
<div class="documentation">
   <p>Long paragraph A</p>
   <p>Long paragraph B</p>
   <p>Long paragraph C</p>
</div>

<script>
/* Logic is:
  - Add a button at the end of div.documentation
  - Hide all div.document p
  - Show div.documentation > p:first-child
  - Add handler to the button; onclick show first div.document p not hidden
  - If all div.document p not hidden, hide button.
*/
</script>
```

To me, the paragraphs of text are manifestly not data. They are content that we are adding mild behaviour to enhance usability, by enabling each concept to be revealed progressively. There could be text before and after this set of paragraphs; it just so happens these ones in the middle have a progressive-reveal animation by way of progressive enhancement.

In the Vue.js world it is not clear to me what the equivalent implementation should be.

I considered three approaches:

**Approach 1: Treat the progressive enhancement section as a Component and pass in Slot content**

This doesn't work, but it felt to me the purest methodology at first. Essentially we treat the paragraphs as the argument to a ProgressiveReveal component that implements behaviour. Treated as a component we can then use the same progressive reveal concept on other pages. But this is clearly breaking the intention of slots and not what they should be used for.

pages/documentation.vue:

```
<script setup>
    import ProgressiveReveal from "@/components/ProgressiveReveal.vue"; 
</script>

<template>
    <p>Introduction text in future maybe</p>
    <ProgressiveReveal>
        <p>Long paragraph A</p>
        <p>Long paragraph B</p>
        <p>Long paragraph C</p>
    </ProgressiveReveal>
    <p>Following text</p>
</template>
```

components/ProgressiveReveal.vue:

Parse out the slot somehow. But the slot is an array of three vue nodes, not HTML. It also would be rendered immediately, which is not what we want.

**Approach 2: Define the animated paragraphs only, within script**

This does work but feels wrong to me - in my world view, long paragraphs of content to me are nothing to do with logic, nor are they symbols like a 'Hello world' status that is acceptable within logic. I view them as content within an overall flow of text that happen to be animated for usability. If text is added above and below, which may well happen in future, we have the odd situation of some of the flow being in one place, but the bit that happens to be animated in a completely different place.

```
<script setup>
myParagraphs = ref([
    '<p>Long paragraph A</p>',
    '<p>Long paragraph B</p>',
    '<p>Long paragraph C</p>',
])
function handleProgressiveReveal() {
// Then implement the button and counter etc to show/hide
}
</script>

<template>
    <p>Introduction text in future maybe</p>
    {{ myParagraphs }}
    <button @click="handleProgressiveReveal">
    <p>Following text</p>
</template>
```

**Approach 3: Mark up the progressive-reveal paragraphs with v-if**

To me this feels least worst but still rather poor, because adding additional paragraphs then have to have junky hard-coded numbers added that really a computer ought to be able to work out for itself. The upside is that at least the semantic structure is clearly preserved and the content is not arbitrarily split into two places.

```
<script setup>
    const counter = ref(0)
</script>

<template>
    <p>Introduction text in future maybe</p>
    <p v-if="counter.value >= 0">Long paragraph A</p>
    <p v-if="counter.value >= 1">Long paragraph B</p>
    <p v-if="counter.value >= 2">Long paragraph C</p>
    <button v-if="counter.value < 3" @click="counter++">
    <p>Following text</p>
</template>
```

---

So what is the best approach for this kind of scenario of essentially trying to add behaviour to large blocks of static text content?

Comment: Is your content truly hard coded paragraph tags that someone is going to type in to a vue component? Usually with vue you're making an app and you are getting your content/data from an api.

Comment: Yes, it is content that has been sent as a finalised document, and is one of the many pages that overall form a complete application with flows between sub-pages and state management between the sub-pages. This documentation page is part of the overall flow, introducing people to the interactivity that follows on the subsequent sub-page. Creating an API just to serve static content would seem overkill and over-complex. Other parts of the overall app will be highly data-driven using APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is static text and not true data binding, I think this is a case where you use methods similar to how you would handle this without Vue, just with a couple Vue helpers to make it nicer.

The method that seems the most straightforward to me is to wrap the expandable paragraphs and get a reference to the wrapper element. When the component loads, loop through the element's children and hide all but the first one.

We still use the counter, but we use it as an index into the wrapper's children to determine which to show next. This eliminates the need for specific indexes in the static text.

Finally, to show/hide the button, we just make a computed property that compares the counter to the number of children:

```
<script setup>
  import { ref, computed, onMounted } from 'vue';
  const counter = ref(0);
  const expandable = ref(null);
  
  onMounted(() => {
    [...expandable.value.children].forEach((paragraph, index) => {
      if (index > 0) {
        paragraph.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  });
  
  function showNext() {
    counter.value++;
    expandable.value.children[counter.value].style.display = 'block';
  }
  
  const allShown = computed(() => counter.value === expandable.value?.children.length - 1);
</script>

<template>
    <p>Introduction text in future maybe</p>
  
    <div ref="expandable">
      <p>Long paragraph A</p>
      <p>Long paragraph B</p>
      <p>Long paragraph C</p>
    </div>
   
    <button v-if="!allShown" @click="showNext()">Click</button>
    <p>Following text</p>
</template>
```

[Link to example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thanks - very kind of you to answer. I will take a look at this more fully early next week as I'm away. However, I see this is doing direct DOM manipulation - isn't that rather away from the general Vue approach that the state is not set directly in the DOM?

Comment: Yes but, its just static text. If there were data binding here this would be bad, as the state of the data and the dom could get out of sync. The only state here really is how many are displayed, and that is still in the vue code as the counter. If you had a v-for loop and pulled this data from an api I would of course say this is bad, but you aren't, so this seems the best way to me.